# Drop all the objects in a database before Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, relationships

I'm practicing JPA features and do the following: change annotations and all this stuff and then run a test. I need to run a test and see the result in a database to ensure I understand things as they are. I would like to drop all the objects somehow to ensure no stale data and tables are remained since the previous test.

There is the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property. I'm using `create` option but it doesn't drop tables for relationships when I change the corresponding mapping.

Thanks for any idea in advance!

Comment: Use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` -it creates and drops the schema automatically when a session is starts and ends

Comment: @krokodilko thx, but it's not the option for me as want to see the result in a database

Comment: If you are using JPA 2.1, then have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro005.htm

Comment: @Luay Abdulraheem Thanks, interesting property. Yes, I'm using JPA 2.1, I tried to set the `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action` but it doesn't drop objects. Btw I'm not using persistence.xml trying to configure it with the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`'s methods `setJpaPropertyMap` and `setJpaProperties`. Is it ok?